# In JavaScript, difference between var foo = function foo(), var foo = function(), regarding private/public/protected?

Tags: javascript

This link - http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html - says the following regarding private members in JavaScript:

```
Private

function Constructor(...) {
  var that = this;
  var membername = value;
  function membername(...) {...}
}

Note: The function statement

function membername(...) {...}

is shorthand for

var membername = function membername(...) {...};
```

**I thought about this, and tried the following: 
Instead of**

```
var membername = function membername(...) {...};
```

**I did just**

```
var membername = function(...) {...};
```

and it seems to have the same effect.

Can anyone verify that these two are exactly the same in all cases? Do they only have the same privacy level/scope when used inside a function? What if they are just in the top-level definition of a JS file?

Thanks.

Comment: They are not the same. But the difference is pretty minor: the one of them has a name and last one doesn't. Check `membername.name` in both cases.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski He's not asking about `function functionName`, he's asking about `var foo = function functionName`, which is different.

Comment: @Barmar this case is described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/3764814)

Comment: This is a pretty good article about named function expressions: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/ .